# Handling user context on logout for user.isAdmin in ReactJs / Uncaught TypeError: user is null

Tags: reactjs, authentication, authorization, mern, logout

I am trying to build a functionality in ReacJs (MERN) app, for my navbar link to '/admin',
to be only visible when user.isAdmin === true.

So my navbar (just an excerpt) looks the follwing:

**Navbar**

```js
import { useAuthContext } from '../hooks/useAuthContext'
import { useIsAdmin } from '../hooks/useAdmin'

const Navbar = () => {
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false)
    const {logout} = useLogout()
    const {user} = useAuthContext()
    const isAdmin = useIsAdmin()

//and on return
{ isAdmin ? <Link to='/admin'><li className='p-4 hover:text-[#00df9a] transition-all duration-500'>Admin {user.name}</li></Link> : <div></div> }
```

I as well made a function to get the user.isAdmin from AuthContext

**useAdmin**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthContext} from '../hooks/useAuthContext';

export function useIsAdmin() {
    const { user } = useAuthContext();
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (user) {
        setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin && user);
      }
    }, [user]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!user || user === null) {
        setIsAdmin(null);
      }
    }, [user]);
  
    return isAdmin;
  }
```

And this works okay, normal user does not see the /admin link, and user.isAdmin does.

However, the problem starts when I try to logout the user.isAdmin, then I receive "Uncaught TypeError: user is null"
as user changes back to Object { user: null }. On contrary,
I do not have that error, if I log out regular user, although it comes back to Object { user: null } as well.

I have tried working on my hook/function with no result, but I am guessing there is some problem with my authContext and global context for user.

So for reference my authContext file and logout.

Any hints and tips would be much appreciated.

**AuthContext**

```js
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return { user: action.payload }
    case 'LOGOUT':
      
      window.localStorage.clear()
      return {user: null}

    case 'DELETE_USER':
      return {...state, user: state.user.filter(u =>
         u.id !== action.payload
      )}    
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
  user: null
})

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: user }) 
    }

  }, [])

  console.log('AuthContext state:', state)

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**useLogout**

```js
import { useAuthContext } from './useAuthContext'

export const useLogout = () => {
    const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()
  
    const logout = () => {
      // remove user from local storage
      localStorage.removeItem('user')
  
      // dispatch logout action
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
    }
  
    return { logout }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i forgot to add user to my if check in navbar. After this change, all works like a charm.

**Navbar**

```
 { isAdmin && user ? <Link to='/admin'><li className='p-4 hover:text-[#00df9a] transition-all duration-500'>Admin {user.name}</li></Link> : <div></div> }
```